# $.Variable in jquery, some confusion in that defined way

Tags: javascript, jquery

i found some codes in validate plug-in jquery. but i don't understand some concept diferences between variable and function:
the code is:

```
$.validator = function(options,form){
    this.settings=$.extend(true,{},validator.defaults,options);
    this.currentForm=form;
    this.init();
}
```

but validator is not a plug-in, because a plug-in jquery must define $.fn.validator. but it also is not a variable because $. sign before it.

Those who can explain it for me???

Comment: Could you provide us a link to the original source. There are many different jquery plugin validators out there ...

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're just adding a function as a property on the `$` (`jQuery`) function. Just like jQuery itself adds `$.extend` and `$.each` and `$.ajax` to it, this validator plugin is adding `$.validator` to it. It's still a plugin (of sorts), it's just that it doesn't define a method that you can call on jQuery *instances*. You can only call the one global version of it.

Given what the function does, it appears to expect to be called via `new`, e.g.:

```
var v = new $.validator();
```

It really should have a capital `V`, and it really should defend against being called directly, as what it does inside is **really wrong** if it's called directly.

Comment: but i found it in jquery.validate.js in site http://jqueryvalidation.org/. it work well

Comment: @LêĐôn: It clearly **also** defines a plugin method `validate` in code you haven't shown, in addition to the `validator` function it adds in the code you quoted. I still think the function you quoted could use some improvement, they're leaving things wide open to horrible side-effects if used incorrectly.

Comment: Constructor $.validator is never used directly it's used in $.fn.validate.

Comment: @jcubic: It shouldn't be a public function **at all** if it's not meant to be used by code outside the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

A function is a piece of data.

A variable is something you can store a piece of data in.

A property on an object is something else you can store a piece of data in.

---

`$` is a variable. It's value is the jQuery function.

`$.validator` is a property of the jQuery function. The code you have is assigning a function to it.

`$.fn.validator` would be a property of the object stored in the `fn` property of the jQuery object. It could also have a value stored in it, but doesn't in your code.

Properties of the `fn` function can be chained from the jQuery object. i.e. with your existing code you could call `$.validator()` but if you has `$.fn.validator` then you could call `$("div").validator()`.